# How to get the count of property in a Kind?

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a **Kind** *Students* which stores the details of favorite colors of all students. They are allowed to pick their favorite color from a set of three colors : `{Red,Blue,Green}`

Let us assume there are 100 students, my code is like this for every student :

```
Entity arya = new Entity("Student","Arya");
arya.setProperty("Color","Red");
Entity robb = new Entity("Student","Robb");
robb.setProperty("Color","Green");
..
..
Entity jon = new Entity("Student","Jon");
jon.setProperty("Color","Blue");
```

How to find out how many students liked a particular color(say Red) in this **Student Kind**  ? What Query I should write to fetch the count ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The number you seek would be the number of items in the result of a query with an equality filter on the `Color` property.

You could use a keys-only query (a special kind of [projection query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries)) for this purpose, faster and less expensive:

> **Keys-only queries**
>
> A *keys-only query* (which is a type of projection query) returns just
>   the keys of the result entities instead of the entities themselves, at
>   lower latency and cost than retrieving entire entities.
>
> ...
>
> A keys-only query is a small operation and counts as only a single
>   entity read for the query itself.

Something along these lines (but note that I'm not a java user, the snippet is based only on the documentation examples)

```
Query<Key> query = Query.newKeyQueryBuilder()
    .setKind("Student")
    .setFilter(PropertyFilter.eq("Color", "Red")
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Dan Cornilescu's answer. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1/datastore.projects.runQuery?projectId=%253CprojectId%253E&_h=5&resource=%257B%250A++%2522query%2522%253A+%250A++%257B%250A++++%2522kind%2522%253A+%250A++++%255B%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522Students%2522%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%255D%252C%250A++++%2522filter%2522%253A+%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522propertyFilter%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522value%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522stringValue%2522%253A+%2522Red%2522%250A++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++%2522op%2522%253A+%2522EQUAL%2522%252C%250A++++++++%2522property%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522Color%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%250A++%257D%250A%257D&) is a direct Datastore API usage. I have prepared the request body for your use-case. You can run it by just adding your Project Id. This will return the entities that matches with the filter then you can count the number of them.